# SQL Server foreign key chaining

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a small problem with planning database structure.

Currently, I have something like this (diagram here: http://i61.tinypic.com/30xa1yp.png):

```
CREATE TABLE ProductionStage (Id int PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE ReportType (Id int PRIMARY KEY)    
CREATE TABLE ProductionLine (Id int PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE PL_RT
(
    IdProductionLine int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProductionLine(Id),
    IdReportType int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ReportType(Id),
    primary key (IdProductionLine, IdReportType)
)

CREATE TABLE PS_RT
(
    IdProductionStage int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProductionStage(Id),
    IdReportType int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ReportType(Id),
    primary key (IdProductionStage, IdReportType)
)

CREATE TABLE Report
(
    IdProductionStage int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PS_RT(Id),
    IdReportType int , -- foreign key from PS_RT(Id) or PL_RT(Id)
    IdProductionLine int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PL_RT(Id)
)
```

I want to prepare a database project for production monitoring. The main concept looks like this. A worker is operating a production line and for each complete production stage he is preparing a report. Report types depend on production stage and production line, but the production stage for each line is the same.

**My question**:

Is that foreign key chaining (like Report -> PS_RT -> ProductionStage || ReportType) good idea in SQL Server, will it be enforcing constraints correctly?

Also I would like to hear your ideas on how to solve that kind of problem, because really I don't have any better idea than this.

Comment: I fail to see what is the purpose of PL_RT and PS_RT tables? Can please explain it?

Comment: There is ralationship between production stage and report type. On certain stages there can be different report types. This relation ship is described by PS_RT table. Second relation is between line and report type. Foreach line there are the same production stages but report types can differ. I think that I made some mistake here (now i've seen it :D). Diagram should look like this i think: http://i60.tinypic.com/etzmzt.jpg

Comment: Maybe I've got it all wrong, but this is what I would do: A worker is filling a report on a given line at a given stage. So you need a table saying what report type(s) are applicable, columns: p.line,p.stage,r.type. Then the report it self would have the same columns + report specific data.